ReadTimeoutError pypi.org on gitlab build
While gitlab build I get error on Dockerfile line
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt


16.71 WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by
'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443):
Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /simple/django/

Previously on this server such problem did not occure.
ping pypi.org -p 443 works okay.
I tried recreate gitlab runner, deleting project folder and docker images, It didn't change anything.
I also tried different version of django in requirements.txt, but it is not the case obviously.
Any help appreciated

I created /etc/docker/daemon.json with
{
  "registry-mirrors": [
    "https://mirror.gcr.io",
    "https://cr.yandex/"
  ],
  "mtu": 1450,
  "dns": ["10.0.0.2", "8.8.8.8"]
}

and it solved the problem
